# How to derive $\langle \boldsymbol{u}', v\rangle + B[\boldsymbol{u}, v;t] = (\boldsymbol{f},v)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $\boldsymbol{u}\in L^2(0,T;H_0^1(U))$, $\boldsymbol{u}'\in L^2(0,T;H^{-1}(U))$ and $\boldsymbol{f}\in L^2(0,T;L^2(U))$. Suppose that
$$
\int_0^T \langle \boldsymbol{u}',\boldsymbol{v}\rangle + B[\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{v};t]\,dt = \int_0^T (\boldsymbol{f},\boldsymbol{v})\,dt,
$$
for all $\boldsymbol{v}\in L^2(0,T;H_0^1(U))$.

**Question:**

How to derive that
$$
\langle \boldsymbol{u}', v\rangle + B[\boldsymbol{u}, v;t] = (\boldsymbol{f},v)
$$
for each $v\in H_0^1(U)$ and a.e. $0\leq t\leq T$.

This is an assertion in Evans' PDE book (section 7.1, Theorem 3) but I can't figure out why. Any hints are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $w \in H^1_0(U)$ and $\varphi \in C^\infty_c((0,T))$ be arbitrary and consider $v \in L^2(0,T;H^1_0(U))$ given by the product $v(x,t) = w(x) \varphi(t)$. Using this $v$ as a test function, we get
$$
\int_0^T [\langle \boldsymbol{u}',\boldsymbol{w}\rangle + B[\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{w};t] - (\boldsymbol{f},\boldsymbol{w})]\varphi(t)\,dt = 0.
$$
Since this holds for all such $\varphi$, we conclude that the map it's integrated against must vanish a.e. in time.  That is, we learn that
$$
\langle \boldsymbol{u}',\boldsymbol{w}\rangle + B[\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{w};t] - (\boldsymbol{f},\boldsymbol{w}) =0
$$
for each such $w$ and a.e. $t \in (0,T)$.  This is what you want upon swapping notation $w \mapsto v$.

Comment: Nice trick, thank you@Glitch

Comment: Happy to help, @Stephen.